# Qt get action clicked from submenu

Tags: python, qt, python-3.x, qt5, pyqt5

I got a menu opening when right clicking on a table, I'd like to get the action name I clicked on. The thing is that I create actions in a loop. Basically each action add the right clicked item to a file (a playlist). So in order to add the item I need to know where.

```
    def menu(self, event):
        self.menu_table = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.tableWidget)
        self.submenu = QtWidgets.QMenu("Add to a playlist")
        list = os.listdir("playlists")
        for i in list:
            self.submenu.addAction(i)
        self.submenu.triggered.connect(MyFunction(ItemClicked))
        self.menu_table.addMenu(self.submenu)
        self.menu_table.exec_(self.tableWidget.mapToGlobal(event))
```

Comment: `QMenu.exec_()` returns the activated action (or `None`).

Comment: Thanks, it does return the activated action, but it also executes the submenu, so even before I rightclick the submenu appears in my mainwindow, is there a way to avoid this ?

Comment: I have added an answer with some example code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your context menu handler should look like this:

```
def menu(self, pos):
    menu = QtWidgets.QMenu()
    submenu = menu.addMenu("Add to a playlist")
    for filename in os.listdir("playlists"):
        submenu.addAction(filename)
    action = menu.exec_(self.mapToGlobal(pos))
    if action is not None:
        print(action.text())
        MyFunction(action)
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, the menu's exec call returns the selected action. What would probably be easiest for you is to use QAction.setData to store the information you need into each action. It's a QVariant, so you can store practically anything. Then, in the result of the "exec" call, you use the selected action's QAction.data to get the value back out. (Sorry if my syntax isn't right...I don't know much Python.)